# Really? What is causing this error in VBA using the IE command?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am having a problem trying to pass variables into this IE command:

*IE.Document.All(**Var1**).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")*

If I type "Response123" instead of Var1 for example - everything works fine. IE opens and the textbox is filled with the value from Range "B5" on my excel sheet. However when I replace it with **Var1** IE crashes and I get a run-time error:

*"'2147023170 (800706be)': automation error the remote procedure call failed"*

I found this link addressing the problem, but the solution doesn't make sense to me. I tried to redeclare the object like it suggested, but it wouldn't compile. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230385

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Populate()

Dim Var1 As String
Dim Var2 As String
Dim Var3 As String

Dim IE As Object

Call Data1 (Var1, Var2, Var3)

DoEvents

'FillInternetForm
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Navigate "https://website.com"
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend

  IE.Document.All(Var1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
  IE.Document.All(Var2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6")
  IE.Document.All(Var3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub


Public Sub Data1 (ByRef Var1 As String, ByRef Var2 As String, ByRef Var3 As String)

Var1 = "Response123"
Var2 = "Response456"
Var3 = "Response789"

End Sub
```

I tried to debug and it gets stuck on:

IE.Document.All(Var1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

However when I hover my cursor over Var1 it shows as "Response123" which is what I want. If I delete Var1 and just manually type "Response123" it works as intended. I'm really at a loss here. Thank you in advance for any help on this one.

Comment: Verify leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: Try switching Var1/2/3 to `Variant` type instead of `String` - sometimes COM interfaces don't want strings.

Comment: @TimWilliams Wow - so I opened it this morning after making absolutely NO changes since the last time I was receiving the error - And it works FINE now. I don't understand. It seems like some kind of intermittent bug and has me feeling very uneasy about releasing this program for daily use at work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified version of your code works for me (see below).  Unless you share more details on your exact use case, we're unlikely to be able to offer much...

```
Public Sub Populate()

    Dim Var1 As String
    Dim IE As Object

    Data1 Var1

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://www.google.com"
    IE.Visible = True
    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))

    IE.Document.All(Var1).Value = "test"

End Sub

Public Sub Data1(ByRef Var1 As String)
    Var1 = "q"
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me and then it doesn't work. I'm not changing anything and it's been happening all day. Do you think this concludes it's a microsoft bug of some kind?

Comment: I changed the variables to variants instead of strings and now it seems to be working without reverting back to the error. So far so good...I hope this is the fix. Thank you!!

Comment: It's impossible for me to guess what the issue might be - web scraping like this is never the most dependable thing to do,so it's often hit-and-miss with some particular content.

Comment: Fair enough. I've ran the program many times now and it's still working flawlessly since changing the variables from strings to variants. Thanks again. I'll keep my fingers crossed.